# Python : Zip extraction exception

Tags: python, python-2.7

I made an automatic extractor for my music catalog.
I wrote my code as sort to work with zips and rar files.
The code is working fine but if there are other kind of files in the working directories, then I receive an error message :

```
raise BadZipfile, "File is not a zip file"
BadZipfile: File is not a zip file
```

That means a mp3 file or anything else is blocking or interrupting the extraction process.
Here's my code :

```
def extraction():
    funcs = {'.rar':rarfile.RarFile, '.zip':zipfile.ZipFile}
    for ArchivesFiles in chemin_zipfiles :    
        truncated_file, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(ArchivesFiles)) 
        if not os.path.exists(truncated_file):
            new_folder = os.makedirs(truncated_file)
            arch_ref = funcs[ext](ArchivesFiles,'r')
            new_folder = os.path.realpath(truncated_file)
            arch_ref.extractall(new_folder)
```

How could I avoid this?

edit :

I made some changes:

```
def extraction():
    funcs = {'.rar':rarfile.RarFile, '.zip':zipfile.ZipFile}
    for ArchivesFiles in chemin_zipfiles :    
        truncated_file, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(ArchivesFiles)) 
        if not os.path.exists(truncated_file):
            new_folder = os.makedirs(truncated_file)
            arch_ref = funcs[ext](ArchivesFiles,'r')
            new_folder = os.path.realpath(truncated_file)
            try:
                arch_ref.extractall(new_folder)
            except BadZipfile:
                continue
            except NotRarFile:
                continue
```

but still receiving an error:

```
raise NotRarFile("Not a Rar archive: "+self.rarfile)
NotRarFile: Not a Rar archive: /Volumes/me/albums/reggae/reggae_dub/._Dubalizer_SubExisteÌncia_freshpoulp.rar
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two ways. First you could catch the exception:

```
try:
    arch_ref.extractall(new_folder)
except BadZipfile:
    continue
```

or you could try to prevent loading non-zip files by filtering the file extension and/or checking the file header.

Comment: Hi, I guess that should work. But I used this code and add some with a NotRarFile exception also and I still get an error message : "File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rarfile.py", line 745, in _parse_real
    raise NotRarFile("Not a Rar archive: "+self.rarfile)"

Comment: Could you add your changed code in the initial post? (Don't replace the existing, just add the new one).

Comment: That's very strange. The except block should catch this error. I'm not sure what's happening.

Comment: Perhaps this is due to the way the file is named? "._Dubalizer_SubExisteÌncia_freshpoulp.rar" I don't know why this file is reported because I don't see it in my directory. I see the archive file correctly named : "Dubalizer_SubExistência_freshpoulp.rar"... What is this prefix : "._" ? I think that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying exceptions wrongly. Instead of:

```
except BadZipfile: 
    continue
except NotRarfile:
    continue
```

you should be doing either:

```
except zipfile.BadZipfile:
    continue
except rarfile.NotRarFile:
    continue
```

or, in a compact manner:

```
except (zipfile.BadZipfile, rarfile.NotRarFile):
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Old post but,

I believe the issue you are having is with the accent you have over the ê.

Because you are trying to access a certain file it will come back as a file does not exist error, but if you were to use that character elsewhere in the code, say trying to print it you would get a UnicodeDecode error.

More information on this here: https://pythonhosted.org/kitchen/unicode-frustrations.html

Comment: Can you add more context to your answer ? Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are… barely more than a link to an external site.